# final 2D array in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, final

If I initialize an array in a Java method like:

```
final double[][] myArray = new double[r][c];
```

Will I be allowed to do this later in the method?

```
myArray[0] = new double[c];
```

Comment: Yes. Didn't you try it for yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll provide you an example of this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int[] finalArray = new int[5];
        finalArray[0] = 10;
        System.out.println(finalArray[0]);
        finalArray[0] = 9001;
        System.out.println(finalArray[0]);
        finalArray = new int[5] //compile error!!!
    }
}
```

This is because the `final` modifier will say that the reference to the array (the pointer) can't change, but the elements of the array (that could have another pointer) can change with no problem.

EDIT:

Another example with 2d array:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int[][] array2d = new int[5][];
        for(int i = 0; i < array2d.length;i++) {
            array2d[i] = new int[6];
        }
        //the size of the rows can change with no problem.
        array2d[0] = new int[8];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the constructive reply. In the 2D case, can I assume that every individual row of my array is another array with a pointer and I am changing their reference when I do that?

Comment: Yes you can, if you try the code it will work. I'll make an update with a sample of this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. For more on arrays http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: It is not obvious how the link conects to the question exactly

Comment: I was concerned with the final keyword because somewhere else, I read that an initialization like this will not allow me to change the reference to the array. Am I not changing the reference in that way?

Comment: You are only change the reference of one element which is allowed.

Comment: I can't see the `final` keyword usage in an array on the link.

Comment: Well this is no special case with multidimensional arrays. Also I needed more characters to make the post.